# remains status code 500 in slim framework

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

When a install by composer:

> /var/www/html/slim# php composer.phar install Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Installing dependencies
>   (including require-dev) from lock file Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files

when i check:

tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log

> Failed opening required 'Slim\Slim.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

My code is:

```
require 'Slim\Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hoheckell/:nome)',
    function($nome = null){
        echo 'Hoheckell' . $nome . '<br />';

    });

$app->run();
```

And remains the Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: If you are using composer, you should use: `require './vendor/autoload.php';` instead of your first line.

Answer (score 0):

Searching a bit more I changed the version that was installed, it was the last stable. God sure as it was found Slim.php file.
The documentation is weak in this part.

This code works:

```
require_once 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/',
    function($nome =  null){
        echo 'Hoheckell: ' . $nome;
    });
$app->run();
```

Comment: How to use composer is explained in the beginning of Slim documentation.

http://docs.slimframework.com/

Comment: there are two options to download, just one of them has the file on folder Slim/Slim.php.
It was the situation.